# How to get the path to the Windows user's home directory (/mnt/c/Users/username) from within WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to get the path to the Windows user's home directory `/mnt/c/Users/username` from within WSL, is it stored somewhere?

If not, is `username` stored somewhere? I'll just assume the `/mnt/c/Users` part doesn't change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply use `wslpath` and `wslvar` together as below:

```
$ wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)"
```

which will return something like this:

> /mnt/c/Users/{USERNAME}

Comment: I don't seem to have `wslvar`. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 WSL2 on Windows 11. How do I install it?

Comment: Answer: `sudo apt install wslu`. Courtesy of https://superuser.com/a/1568668/110087

Answer (score 7):

vGet it using cmd.exe and parse it to WSL path using wslpath (requires an updated WSL with wslpath installed):

**Bash**

```
WIN_HOME_RAW="$(cmd.exe /c "<nul set /p=%UserProfile%" 2>/dev/null)"
WIN_HOME="$(wslpath $WIN_HOME_RAW)"
```

**Fish**

```
set WIN_HOME_RAW (cmd.exe /c "<nul set /p=%UserProfile%" 2>/dev/null)
set -gx WIN_HOME (wslpath $WIN_HOME_RAW)
```

Comment: You should probably enclose ``$WIN_HOME_RAW`` in double quotes... It is not uncommon to have spaces in the user name. ``WIN_HOME="$(wslpath "$WIN_HOME_RAW")"``.

Comment: how can I append subfolders to this path? e.g.: use this path and append at the end /desktop in order to create an alias for win-desktop?

Comment: Why not have the raw path as `cmd.exe /c "echo %UserProfile%"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to get the User Profile variable and convert into WSL path using wslpath built-in:

```
WIN_USER_PROFILE="$(wslpath $(powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "\$Env:UserProfile"))"
```

Comment: You should probably enclose ``$(powershell.exe ...)`` in double quotes... It is not uncommon to have spaces in the user name.